# jQuery $.fn is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Directly DOWN VOTED?**

Do I missing anything that `$.fn.` is not working properly. Whereas I have other module this functionality is working like charm.

I am getting some weird error in jQuery. I am cropping image using jquery.jrac.js file and unfortunately I am getting `TypeError: $.fn.jracIMG is not a function` while accessing function like this way `$.fn.jracIMG("", param);`

I have added jquery.js file properly.

If I remove `$.fn.` from `jracIMG`, in library file itself then it gives some other weird error like `$(elem).find("img").jrac({`

Below is a function I am using

```
    (function( $ ){

  $.fn.jrac = function(options) {

    // Default settings
    var settings = {
      'crop_width': 200,
      'crop_height': 100,
      // The two following properties define the crop position (relative to the
      // image).
      'crop_x': 0,
      'crop_y': 0,
      'crop_resize': true,
      'crop_aspect_ratio': null,
      'image_width': null,
      'image_height': null,
      'zoom_min': 100,
      'zoom_max': 3000,
      'zoom_label': '',
      'viewport_image_surrounding': false, // Set the viewport to surround the image on load
      'viewport_width': null,
      'viewport_height': null,
      'viewport_resize': true,
      // The two following properties allow to position the content (negative
      // value allowed). It can be use to focus the viewport on the cropped
      // part of the image.
      'viewport_content_left': 0,
      'viewport_content_top': 0,
      // Submit here a callback function (context is the viewport).
      'viewport_onload': null
    };

    // Apply the resize and crop tools to each images
    return this.each(function() {

      if (!$(this).is('img')) {
        return;
      }

      // Read options
      var destroy = false;
      if ( typeof(options) == 'object' ) {
        $.extend( settings, options );
      }
      else if (options == 'destroy') {
        destroy = true;
      }

      var $image = $(this);

      // Test if jrac was previously run
      var jrac_loaded = false;
      if ($image.parent().hasClass('jrac_viewport')) {
        jrac_loaded = true;
      }

      if (jrac_loaded && destroy) {
        // Unload jrac if asked
        $image.draggable("destroy");
        $image.parent().find('.jrac_crop').remove();
        $image.parent().parent().find('.jrac_zoom_slider').remove();
        $image.parent().append($image.data('original')); // restore original image
        $image.parent().unwrap(); // remove container
        $image.unwrap(); // remove viewport
        $image.remove(); // remove image which was altered (in its css attributes)
      }
      else {
        // Record image before some of its attributes get altered by some
        // jrac css or some user size or proportion changes.
        $image.data('original', $image.clone());
      }

      // Do nothing more if destroy is asked
      if (destroy) {
        return;
      }

      // Prepare image
      if (!jrac_loaded) {
        $image.hide().css('position','absolute').wrap('<div class="jrac_container"><div class="jrac_viewport"></div></div>');
      }

      // Get viewport and container references
      var $viewport = $image.parent();
      var $container = $viewport.parent();

      // Add a waiting on load input image
      var $loading = $('<div class="jrac_loading" />');
      $viewport.append($loading);

      // The following procedure hold business intend to be run once the image
      // is loaded (load event).
      var image_load_handler = function(){

        // Add some custom properties to $image
        $.extend($image, {
          scale_proportion_locked: true,
          originalWidth: $image.width(),
          originalHeight: $image.height()
        });

        // Set given optional image size
        $image.width(settings.image_width).height(settings.image_height);

        // Apply the viewport image surrounding is asked
        if (settings.viewport_image_surrounding) {
          $viewport.width($image.width()).height($image.height());
        }
        else {
          $viewport.width(settings.viewport_width).height(settings.viewport_height);
        }

        // Set the viewport content position for the image
        $image.css({'left': settings.viewport_content_left, 'top': settings.viewport_content_top});

        // Create the zoom widget which permit to resize the image
        if (!jrac_loaded) {
          if (settings.zoom_label) {
              var $zoom_label = $('<div class="jrac_zoom_slider_label">'+settings.zoom_label+'</div>');
              $container.append($zoom_label);
          }
          var $zoom_widget = $('<div class="jrac_zoom_slider"><div class="ui-slider-handle"></div></div>')
          .slider({
            value: $image.width(),
            min: settings.zoom_min,
            max: settings.zoom_max,
            start: function(event, ui) {
              $.extend($zoom_widget,{
                on_start_width_value: ui.value,
                on_start_height_value: $image.height()
              })
            },
            slide: function(event, ui) {
              var height = Math.round($zoom_widget.on_start_height_value * ui.value / $zoom_widget.on_start_width_value);
              $image.height(height);
              $image.width(ui.value);
              $viewport.observator.notify('jrac_image_height', height);
              $viewport.observator.notify('jrac_image_width', ui.value);
            }
          });
          $container.append($zoom_widget);

          // Make the viewport resizeable
          if (settings.viewport_resize) {
            $viewport.resizable();
          }

          // Enable the image draggable interaction
          $image.draggable({
            drag: function(event, ui) {
              if (ui.position.left != ui.originalPosition.left) {
                $viewport.observator.notify('jrac_crop_x', $viewport.observator.crop_position_x());
              }
              if (ui.position.top != ui.originalPosition.top) {
                $viewport.observator.notify('jrac_crop_y', $viewport.observator.crop_position_y());
              }
            }
          });

          // Build the crop element
          var $crop = $('<div class="jrac_crop"><div class="jrac_crop_drag_handler"></div></div>')
          .css({
            'width': settings.crop_width,
            'height': settings.crop_height,
            'left':settings.crop_x+settings.viewport_content_left,
            'top':settings.crop_y+settings.viewport_content_top
          }).draggable({
            containment: $viewport,
            handle: 'div.jrac_crop_drag_handler',
            drag: function(event, ui) {
              if (ui.position.left != ui.originalPosition.left) {
                $viewport.observator.notify('jrac_crop_x', $viewport.observator.crop_position_x());
              }
              if (ui.position.top != ui.originalPosition.top) {
                $viewport.observator.notify('jrac_crop_y', $viewport.observator.crop_position_y());
              }
            }
          });
          if (settings.crop_resize) {
            $crop.resizable({
              containment: $viewport,
              aspectRatio: settings.crop_aspect_ratio,
              resize: function(event, ui) {
                if (ui.size.width != ui.originalSize.width) {
                  $viewport.observator.notify('jrac_crop_width', $crop.width());
                }
                if (ui.size.height != ui.originalSize.height) {
                  $viewport.observator.notify('jrac_crop_height', $crop.height());
                }
              }
            })
          }
          $viewport.append($crop);
        }

        // Extend viewport witch usefull objects as it will be exposed to user
        // functions interface
        $.extend($viewport, {
          $container: $container,
          $image: $image,
          $crop: $crop,
          $zoom_widget: $zoom_widget,
          // Let me introduce the following Terminator's friend which handle the
          // creation of the viewport events.
          observator: {
            items: {},
            // Register an event with a given element
            register: function(event_name, element, onevent_callback) {
              if (event_name && element) {
                this.items[event_name] = {
                  element: element,
                  callback: onevent_callback
                };
              }
            },
            // Unregister an event
            unregister: function(event_name) {
              delete this.items[event_name];
            },
            // Trigger an event and optionally supply a value
            notify: function(event_name, value) {
              if (this.items[event_name]) {
                var element = this.items[event_name].element;
                var onevent_callback = this.items[event_name].callback;
                element.trigger(event_name,[$viewport, value]);
                if ($.isFunction(onevent_callback)) {
                  onevent_callback.call($viewport, event_name, element, value);
                }
              }
              $image.trigger('jrac_events',[$viewport]);
            },
            notify_all: function() {
              this.notify('jrac_crop_x', this.crop_position_x());
              this.notify('jrac_crop_y', this.crop_position_y());
              this.notify('jrac_crop_width', $crop.width());
              this.notify('jrac_crop_height', $crop.height());
              this.notify('jrac_image_width', $image.width());
              this.notify('jrac_image_height', $image.height());
            },
            // Return crop x position relative to $image
            crop_position_x: function() {
              return $crop.position().left - $image.position().left;
            },
            // Return crop y position relative to $image
            crop_position_y: function() {
              return $crop.position().top - $image.position().top;
            },
            // Does the crop is completely inside the image?
            crop_consistent: function() {
              return this.crop_position_x()>=0 && this.crop_position_y()>=0
              && this.crop_position_x() + $crop.width() + parseInt($crop.css('border-width'),10)*2  <=$image.width()
              && this.crop_position_y() + $crop.height() + parseInt($crop.css('border-width'),10)*2 <=$image.height();
            },
            // Set a property (which his name is one of the event) with a given
            // value then notify this operation
            set_property: function(that, value) {
              value = parseInt(value);
              if (isNaN(value)) {
                return;
              }
              switch (that) {
                case 'jrac_crop_x':
                  $crop.css('left',value + $image.position().left);
                  break;
                case 'jrac_crop_y':
                  $crop.css('top',value + $image.position().top);
                  break;
                case 'jrac_crop_width':
                  $crop.width(value);
                  break;
                case 'jrac_crop_height':
                  $crop.height(value);
                  break;
                case 'jrac_image_width':
                  if ($image.scale_proportion_locked) {
                    var image_height = Math.round($image.height() * value / $image.width());
                    $image.height(image_height);
                    this.notify('jrac_image_height', image_height);
                  }
                  $image.width(value);
                  $zoom_widget.slider('value', value);
                  break;
                case 'jrac_image_height':
                  if ($image.scale_proportion_locked) {
                    var image_width = Math.round($image.width() * value / $image.height());
                    $image.width(image_width);
                    this.notify('jrac_image_width', image_width);
                    $zoom_widget.slider('value', image_width);
                  }
                  $image.height(value);
                  break;
              }
              this.notify(that, value);
            }
          }
        });

        // Hide the loading notice
        $loading.hide();
        $loading.remove();

        // Finally display the image
        $image.show();

        // Trigger the viewport_onload callback
        if ($.isFunction(settings.viewport_onload)) {
          settings.viewport_onload.call($viewport);
          $viewport.observator.notify_all();
        }
      };

      // When an image is using an src image "data" URL scheme then it appear
      // that the image load event never get fired. Then fire directly
      // image_load_handler() in that case.
      var src = $image.attr('src');
      if (/^data:image/.test(src)) {
         image_load_handler();
      }
      else {
        src = src + (src.search(/\?/)<0?'?':'&') + 'jracrandom=' + (new Date()).getTime();
        $('<img>').attr('src', src).load(image_load_handler);
      }
    });
  };
})( jQuery );
```

And this

```
$.fn.jracIMG = function(elem,param) {
        $(elem).find("img").jrac({
            'crop_resize':param["crop_resize"],
            'viewport_resize': param["viewport_resize"],
            'crop_width': param["crop_width"],
            'crop_height': param["crop_height"],
            'crop_x': param["crop_x"],
            'crop_y': param["crop_y"],
            'image_width' : param["image_width"] ? param["image_width"] : 550,
            'viewport_onload': function() {            
                var $viewport = this;
                //$viewport.$image.draggable("destroy");
                var inputs = $viewport.$container.parent('.pane').find('.coords input:hidden');

                var events = ['jrac_crop_x', 'jrac_crop_y', 'jrac_crop_width', 'jrac_crop_height', 'jrac_image_width', 'jrac_image_height'];
                for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                    var event_name = events[i];
                    // Register an event with an element.
                    $viewport.observator.register(event_name, inputs.eq(i));
                    // Attach a handler to that event for the element.
                    inputs.eq(i).bind(event_name, function(event, $viewport, value) {
                        $(this).val(value);
                    })
                            // Attach a handler for the built-in jQuery change event, handler
                            // which read user input and apply it to relevent viewport object.
                            .change(event_name, function(event) {
                                var event_name = event.data;
                                $viewport.$image.scale_proportion_locked = $viewport.$container.parent('.pane').find('.coords input:checkbox').is(':checked');
                                $viewport.observator.set_property(event_name, $(this).val());
                            });
                }
                $viewport.$container.find(".imgnatsize").remove();
                $viewport.$container.append('<div class=imgnatsize>Image natual size: '
                        + $viewport.$image.originalWidth + ' x '
                        + $viewport.$image.originalHeight + '</div>')
            }
        })
                // React on all viewport events.
                .bind('jrac_events', function(event, $viewport) {
                    var inputs = $(this).parents('.pane').find('.coords input');
                    //inputs.css('background-color', ($viewport.observator.crop_consistent()) ? 'chartreuse' : 'salmon');
                    if ($viewport.observator.crop_consistent()) {
                        inputs.removeClass('_err').addClass('_suc');
                    } else {
                        inputs.removeClass('_suc').addClass('_err');
                    }
                });


    }
    $.fn.containerFix = function(container) {
         container = $(container);
        var mTop = container.outerHeight() / 2;
        container.css({
            'margin-top': -mTop,
        });
    };

    $.fn.createCropPanel = function() {
        var elem;
        elem = "<div class='pane clearfix'>";
        elem += "<img class='cropPreview' />";
        elem += "<form class='cropPanelForm' method='post'>";
        elem += "<div class='coords'>";
        elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='cropx'/>";
        elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='cropy'/>";
        elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='cropw'/>";
        elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='croph'/>";
        elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='imagew'/>";
        elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='imageh'/>";
        elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='imagefilename'/>";
        elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='imagefiledirectory'/>";
        elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='is_dashboard' value='0'/>";
        elem += "<input type='submit' value='Crop & Save' class='btn-cta btn-cta-sm b-styled' />";
        elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='logofilename'/>";
        elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='logofiledirectory'/>";
        elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='sliderfilename'/>";
        elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='sliderfiledirectory'/>";
        elem += "</div>";
        elem += "</form>";
        elem += "</div>";
        return elem;
    };

$.fn.createCropPanelOnboard = function() {
    var elem;
    elem = "<div class='pane clearfix'>";
    elem += "<img class='cropPreview' />";
    elem += "<form class='cropPanelForm' method='post'>";
    elem += "<div class='coords'>";
    elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='cropx'/>";
    elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='cropy'/>";
    elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='cropw'/>";
    elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='croph'/>";
    elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='imagew'/>";
    elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='imageh'/>";
    elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='imagefilename'/>";
    elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='imagefiledirectory'/>";
    elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='is_dashboard' value='0'/>";
    //elem += "<input type='submit' id='crop_btn' value='Crop & Save' class='btn-cta btn-cta-sm b-styled' />";
    elem += "<a href='javascript:;' class='btn-cta btn-cta-sm b-styled' id='crop_btn' >Crop & Save</a>";
        elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='logofilename'/>";
    elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='logofiledirectory'/>";
    elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='sliderfilename'/>";
    elem += "<input type='hidden'  name='sliderfiledirectory'/>";
    elem += "</div>";
    elem += "</form>";
    elem += "</div>";
    return elem;
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Solution**

I placed those function definitions in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //Both files code goes here
});
```

and now it is working like a charm.

Comment: Where is `$.fn.jracIMG` defined? It is not in the code you posted, where you only have `window.jracIMG`.

Comment: @trincot I have updated code. Please checl.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Did you debug and check right after(!) the definition of `$.fn.jracIMG` that the function exists? Something like `console.log($.fn.jracIMG);`

Comment: @trincot it is `TypeError: $.fn.jracIMG is not a function` whereas I have added this function in js file and have added that file before it use it.

Comment: @trincot, sorry. Correct and wrote console output. It is also creating issue for chaining function.

Comment: But please put the debugging code inside your js file, right after the assignment. `console.log($.fn.jracIMG);` cannot produce the `TypeError` you mention, so evidently you did something else. Could you please do it like this, *inside* the js file, and *right after* the definition of `$.fn.jracIMG`? Can you also ensure this statement gets executed. If you get another error first, then you have proof you never made it to the function definition, and you have referenced that function before defining it.

Comment: @trincot, console.log() output after putting it just after function definition. `function(elem, param)`

Comment: OK, which other libraries you use that might set `$`? Any conflict possible with `$`? Have you tried accessing your function with `jQuery.fn.jracIMG`?

Comment: @trincot, same error `TypeError: jQuery.fn.jracIMG is not a function`. Using this `https://github.com/trepmag/jrac`

Comment: @trincot, after adding file and before accessing it I am getting `undefined`.  Whereas in file where this function resides, it is giving `function(elem, param)`

Comment: Please provide in your question all the `<script src=` tags you use and where they are placed in your document, and also where your `script` is that wants to call `$.fn.jracIMG`.

Comment: @trincot, Thank you so much for your efforts. I figured it out. I placed those function definitions in `$(document).ready(function(){});` and now it is working like a charm.

Comment: OK, good to hear. Important still is: do you understand why it failed? I am quite sure you were accessing the function before it was defined.

Answer (score 2):

I placed those function definitions, functions in files, in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //Both files code goes here
});
```

and now it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue in the past, have you tried using a CDN instead of hosting the code yourself? 
I would suggest using Google's CDN as they have really fast servers and won't slow things down on the client side. You and use `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` instead of your file. 
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Do not know why but still it give error like `TypeError: $(...).jrac is not a function`